# $\sum k! = 1! +2! +3! + \cdots + n!$ ,is there a generic formula for this?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, factorial

I came across a question where I needed to find the sum of the factorials of the first $n$ numbers. So I was wondering if there is any generic formula for this?

Like there is a generic formula for the series:

$$ 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + \cdots + n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2} $$

or

$$ 1^{2} + 2^{2} + 3^{2} + 4^{2} + \cdots + n^{2} = \frac{n(n+1)(2n + 1)}{6} $$

> Is there is any formula for:
>
> $$ 1! +2! +3! + 4! + \cdots + n! $$
>
> and
>
> $$ {1!}^2 +{2!}^2 +{3!}^2 + \cdots + {n!}^2 $$?

Thanks in advance.

If not, is there any research on making this type of formula?
Because I am interested.

Comment: Mathematica says that: $$\sum_{n=1}^{N}{n!}=-1-(-1)¡-(-1)^{N}\cdot\Gamma{(2+N)}\cdot(-N-2)¡,$$ where $n¡$ is the [subfactorial](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Derangement)

Comment: See also: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FactorialSums.html

Comment: I'd recommend checking out [Euler's continued fraction formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_continued_fraction_formula#Euler's_formula).
However, also note: $$\sum_{n=1}^{N}n!=1+2\left(1+3\left(1+4(1+\dots)\right)\right)$$

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but there is the following related identity: $$ \sum_{k = 0}^n k \cdot k! = (n + 1)! - 1 $$

Answer (score 43, accepted):

(Too long for a comment)

I don't know if there's a simpler form, but the sum of factorials has certainly been well-studied. In the literature, it is referred to as either the *[left factorial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeftFactorial.html)* (though this term is also used for the more common subfactorial) or the *[Kurepa function](http://arxiv.org/abs/0704.0068)* (after the Balkan mathematician Đuro Kurepa).

In particular, for $K(n)=\sum\limits_{j=0}^{n-1}j!$ (using the notation $K(n)$ after Kurepa), we have as an analytic continuation the integral representation

$$K(z)=\int_0^\infty \exp(-t)\frac{t^z-1}{t-1}\mathrm dt,\quad \Re z>0$$

and a further continuation to the left half-plane is possible from the functional equation $K(z)-K(z-1)=\Gamma(z)$

An expression in terms of "more usual" special functions, equivalent to the one in Shaktal's comment, is

$$K(z)=\frac1{e}\left(\Gamma(z+1) E_{z+1}(-1)+\mathrm{Ei}(1)+\pi i\right)$$

where [$E_p(z)$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.19) and [$\mathrm{Ei}(z)$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/6.2.E5) are the exponential integrals.

The sum of squares of factorials does not seem to have a simple closed form, but [the sequence is listed in the OEIS](http://oeis.org/A104344). One can, however, derive an integral representation that could probably be used as a starting point for analytic continuation. In particular, we have

$$\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}(j!)^2=2\int_0^\infty \frac{t^n-1}{t-1} K_0(2\sqrt t)\mathrm dt$$

where $K_0(z)$ is the modified Bessel function of the second kind.

Answer (score 43):

In addition to the special functions given by J.M., an asymptotic expansion can be computed
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^n k!
&=n!\left(\frac11+\frac1n+\frac1{n(n-1)}+\frac1{n(n-1)(n-2)}+\dots\right)\\
&=n!\left(1+\frac1n+\frac1{n^2}+\frac2{n^3}+\frac5{n^4}+\frac{15}{n^5}+O\left(\frac1{n^6}\right)\right)\\
&=\sqrt{2\pi n}\frac{n^n}{e^n}\left(1+\frac{13}{12n}+\frac{313}{288n^2}+\frac{108041}{51840n^3}+\frac{12857717}{2488320n^4}+O\left(\frac1{n^5}\right)\right)
\end{align}
$$
As with most asymptotic expansions, the series does not converge, and cannot be used to get an exact answer, but it gives a good approximation.

**Edit:** I forgot to give
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^nk!^2
&=n!^2\left(\frac11+\frac1{n^2}+\frac1{n^2(n-1)^2}+\frac1{n^2(n-1)^2(n-2)^2}+\dots\right)\\
&=n!^2\left(1+\frac1{n^2}+\frac1{n^4}+\frac2{n^5}+\frac4{n^6}+\frac{10}{n^7}+O\left(\frac1{n^8}\right)\right)\\
&=2\pi\frac{n^{2n+1}}{e^{2n}}\left(1+\frac1{6n}+\frac{73}{72n^2}+\frac{1049}{6480n^3}+\frac{157541}{155520n^4}+O\left(\frac1{n^5}\right)\right)
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Where do the second and third expansions come from? I can guess that the third expansion probably has to do with Stirlings formula but a link to a derivation might be insightful

Comment: The second expansions come from expanding $\frac1{n(n-1)}=\frac1{n^2}+\frac1{n^3}+\frac1{n^4}+\dots$, etc. The third expansions come from applying the expansion for $n!=\sqrt{2\pi n}\frac{n^n}{e^n}\left(1+\frac1{12n}+\frac1{288n^2}-\frac{139}{51840n^3}+\dots\right)$

Answer (score 9):

For what concerns the first one, yes there is.

$$\sum_{k = 0}^{n} k! = \frac{i\pi}{e} + \frac{\text{Ei}(1)}{e} - \frac{(-1)^n\ \Gamma[n+2]\ \Gamma[-n-1, -1]}{e}$$

Where Ei is the Exponential Integral function, and $\Gamma[x]$ is the Euler Gamma Function whilst $\Gamma[x, n]$ is the upper incomplete Gamma Function.

**More on IGF**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function

**More on Ei**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral

Answer (score 1):

With the help of Maple, we get for $m,n\in\mathbb{N}_+$:

$$\sum_{k=1}^nk!^m=\ _2F_0(1,2\$m;\ ;1)-(n+1)!^m\ _2F_0(1,(n+2)\$m;\ ;1),$$

where [$_2F_0$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function#The_series_2F0) is a [generalized hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function) and $a\$m$ is the sequence $a_1,...,a_m$ with $a_1,...,a_m=a$.

This result seems to be new to  [Wolfram Mathworld: Factorial Sums](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FactorialSums.html) and to [The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences (OEIS)](https://oeis.org/) and should be reported there.

Comment: That result may be formally correct but both of those hypergeometric functions will not evaluate to finite values.