# The closed form of $\sum_{n=1}^{x}n!$

Tags: summation, factorial, closed-form

Let
$$y=\sum_{n=1}^{x}n!$$
be the sum of consecutive factorials.

What is closed form for $y$ in terms of $x$? Wolfram Alpha says that $$y=-(-1)^x\Gamma(x+2)(!(-x-2))-!(-1)-1$$ where $!x$ is subfactorial function of $x$, but there isn't any step-by-step method available. Can you explain how solve this?

Comment: Have you tried induction on $x$?

Comment: For others reading this, note that $!x$ is not a typo but rather the so-called subfactorial. (It would be helpful to put that into your question.)

Comment: see [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/227551/sum-k-1-2-3-cdots-n-is-there-a-generic-formula-for-this) and [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FactorialSums.html).

Comment: Given @aziiri's first link, this is essentially a duplicate question. But I don't find myself terribly satisfied by the answers in those questions.

Comment: Me too, the result is quite ugly. But this the case of many finite sums, for example the harmonic sum also have no beautiful closed form (some will consider $H_n$ a closed form).

Comment: You may want to look at http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/AeqB.html