# How to find a closed form of this simple factorial sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form

$$S_1=1\\ S_n=n!+S_{n-1}$$
Is there a simple way to express $S_n$ without summing up all the previous terms? Sorry I haven't put any effort in the problem but I don't know where to start.

So this means that $$S_1=1\\ S_2=3\\ S_3=9\\ S_4=33$$ and so on. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Even if you (understandably) want to avoid summing up a series like this, it's still a good idea to compute the first few terms in order to get a feel for the sequence. (And it's an easy thing to include in your question.)

Comment: @Semiclassical Done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to a CAS, there is effectively a closed form $$S_n=-(-1)^n \Gamma (n+2)~ \text{Subfactorial}[-n-2]-2 ~\text{Subfactorial}[-3]+1$$ in which function $\text{Subfactorial}[k]$ gives the number of permutations of $n$ objects that leave no object fixed.

I bet that this will not be very practical.

Answer (score 0):

$S_n=1!+2!+\cdots + n!$. Now, a detailed discussion of this sum can be obtained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/227551/sum-k-1-2-3-cdots-n-is-there-a-generic-formula-for-this).

Answer (score 0):

OEIS sequence [A007489](http://oeis.org/A007489).  No "closed form" is listed.