# Summation of factorials.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, factorial

How do I go about summing this :

$$\sum_{r=1}^{n}r\cdot (r+1)!$$

I know how to sum up $r\cdot r!$ But I am not able to do a similar thing with this.

Comment: How do you sum up $r*r!$? The two sums are closely related (try breaking down $(r+1)!$ into smaller parts)

Comment: I helped with the formatting of your question.  Please look at the modifications I made so that it will be easier in the future to use LATEX (mathJAX) formatting.  There is a good guide here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @bburGsamohT by writing r as (r+1-1) then it becomes r+1! -  r!  In that the middle terms cancel and the answer comes out to be n+1!-1!

Comment: I found out that the summation equals $\left(n+2\right)!-2-\sum_{r=1}^{n}\left(r+1\right)!$, but I don't think that makes things more easy. Have a look at [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/227551/75923) for that.

Comment: @drhab but I think the aim of this question is to somehow manipulate it like the same way we do for r.r!

Comment: There is a nice result for $r.r!$ but unfortunately not for $r.(r+1)!$,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Making use of:

$$r.\left(r+1\right)!=\left(r+2-2\right).\left(r+1\right)!=\left(r+2\right)!-2.\left(r+1\right)!$$

we write the summation as:

$$\left[\left(n+2\right)!-2.\left(n+1\right)!\right]+\left[\left(n+1\right)!-2.n!\right]+\cdots+\left[4!-2.3!\right]+\left[3!-2.2!\right]$$

leading to:

$$\sum_{r=1}^{n}r.\left(r+1\right)!=\left(n+2\right)!-2-\sum_{r=1}^{n}\left(r+1\right)!$$

So finding an expression for it is in essence the same as finding an expression for: $$\sum_{r=1}^{n}r!$$

For this have a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/227551/75923).

Comment: Oh now I understood what you meant.