# what is remainder from division of A by 10?

Tags: sequences-and-series, factorial

What is remainder from division of $A$ by $10$? $A=0!+3!+6!+9!+…+81!$

I thought I was kind of expert in high school mathematics until I was hit in punch by my brother who is in secondary school. Guys I will really appreciate if anyone can get me out of this mess.

Comment: Hint:  what is the remainder on dividing $6!$ by $10$?

Comment: If any number contains $2$ and $5$ as a factor, then it can be divisible by $10$.

So, $n\geq 5$, $10\mid n!$.

Answer (score 1):

$6!, 9!, 12!, ... 81!$ will all end in 0 since they each a 5 and a 2 as factors.  So to find the units place, just look at $0! = 1$ and $3! = 6$.  So your units place for the sum will be $1 + 6 + 0 + 0 + 0 + ... + 0 = 7$.  And there's your remainder.

Comment: I can't believe how easy it was. I spent almost 2 hours to find sum of the sequence while I didn't even need it. Thank you very much

Comment: Is there any specific formula for Sum of such factorial sequences?

Comment: You can check this out: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/227551/sum-k-1-2-3-cdots-n-is-there-a-generic-formula-for-this  But I don't think you'll find a formula that's nearly as simple as it is for an arithmetic series or a sum of squares!  The terms get very big, very quickly.  Google's telling me 81! = 5.797126e+120.  I don't think you'll be asked for the sums of many factorials.  This was a bit of a trick question trying to get you to notice that for every n >= 5, n! will be a multiple of 10.